# Pandas: Adding Two Columns From Two Dataframes With Different Time Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes (let's call them `df_1` and `df_2`):

```
epoch_ns                        net
1635747118006744249               64.75
1635747144020144197             -135.27

epoch_ns                        net
1635747085588589391              -15.25
1635747224568306088             -775.29
1635747242571214411               24.66
```

I would like to add both `df_1['net']` and `df_2['net']` together to have a resultant dataframe like this:

```
epoch_ns                        net
1635747085588589391              -15.25
1635747118006744249                49.5
1635747144020144197             -150.52
1635747224568306088             -910.56
1635747242571214411             −910.56
```

One way is to resample both frames with 1ms frequency (losing the precision) but it could use a lot of memory when my both frames have a long time horizontal.

Any other more efficient way (time wise and memory wise)?

Comment: ```df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])```

Comment: can you explain the logic of the calculations? It doesn't look like a sum for all

Comment: @mozway you can think of net as "net profit", frame #1 has net profit for Apple stock, and frame #2 has net profit for Google stock.  And I want to see the total profit of my portfolio at different time points.  Potentially, I could have 100 stocks in my portfolio.  But I simplified in my post to have just 2.

Comment: That's what I thought but can you double check the example?

Comment: @mozway good catch.  fixed. :)

Comment: @HCSF still looks incorrect to me, but check my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.concat`, and `cumsum`.

As you already have a cumulated sum as input, you first need to take the diff:

```
(pd.concat([df1.assign(net=df1['net'].diff().combine_first(df1['net'])),
            df2.assign(net=df2['net'].diff().combine_first(df2['net'])),
           ])
   .sort_values(by='epoch_ns')
   .assign(net=lambda d:d['net'].cumsum())
 )
```

output:

```
              epoch_ns     net
0  1635747085588589391  -15.25
0  1635747118006744249   49.50
1  1635747144020144197 -150.52
1  1635747224568306088 -910.56
2  1635747242571214411 -110.61
```

intermediate step to uncumulate the net (example on df2):

```
>>> df2.assign(raw=df2['net'].diff().combine_first(df2['net']))
              epoch_ns     net     raw
0  1635747085588589391  -15.25  -15.25
1  1635747224568306088 -775.29 -760.04
2  1635747242571214411   24.66  799.95
```

##### original answer

```
(pd.concat([df1,df2])
   .sort_values(by='epoch_ns')
   .assign(net=lambda d:d['net'].cumsum())
 )
```

Output:

```
              epoch_ns     net
0  1635747085588589391  -15.25
0  1635747118006744249   49.50
1  1635747144020144197  -85.77
1  1635747224568306088 -861.06
2  1635747242571214411 -836.40
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  Now I know why you said my example is incorrect -- my net in each row in each data frame represents the cumulative net profit at that moment.  I believe what you have in mind is that the net in each row in each data frame represents the profit just generated at that point (excluding the previous).

Comment: @HCSF I see now, you need to uncumulate by taking the diff. I still have a difference for the last value though…

Comment: You are right that the value in my last row is still incorrect.  Thanks for your solution.  Tho, my understanding is that vectorized operation is faster than iteration in pandas.  I wonder whether there is a vectorized solution.

Comment: @HCSF this solution is vectorized

Comment: I thought when pandas applies a `lambda` function on a column, it becomes an iteration, no?

Comment: With `apply` most of the time yes, here this is just an assignment, there is no loop involved. This is just a syntax to keep everything chained. But you could do `df['net'] = df['net'].cumsum()` instead.

Comment: you are right.  `cumsum()` itself is vectorized. thanks!